# Algorithm to find same element from a point in a random matrix

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix

I'm wondering on how can I do to find, in a random matrix, each same elements from a particular point, and around this point.

It's easier to explain in an example :

[image]

So, in green it is the point that the player chooses. How can I get the position of all these "X" (only lines and columns, not diagonal) ? I thought about an algorithm like Dijkstra or Bellman Ford ?

I hope you understand, and sorry for my bad english.

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand. There are a couple more X at the same distance from the green X that is not marked red. why?

Comment: Use DFS/BFS on the graph defined by the grid. Start the traversal from the chosen position.

Comment: Thanks, lead_the_zeppelin : it's because I only want to take the same points in line and column, not in diagonal

Comment: You are looking for [Flood Fill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like [depth-first search (DFS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) or [breadth-first search (BFS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) is probably what you're looking for.

DFS:

- Start at the chosen cell.
- Recursively explore in all directions, but don't explore already visited cells.