# Random matrix : from an index i,j find same values

Tags: java, matrix

I try to get position of all same elements from a particular point given by a player. Elements have to be sides by sides : only columns and lines, not diagonal. I have to get the position of the bigger group of elements.

The goal is to have the best score, the rule :

- A player give a position
- I have to get all these positions in a list
- Tell him the score (number of elements in the list)
- Then do a random between 1 and 2 on these positions
- Show the new matrix to other players

So, for the moment with my code, I can have the positions on the same line and column, but not all the positions.

This is my code like:

```
    if(y > 0) 
        if(grille[x][y] == grille[x][y-1]) 
            unvisited.add(new Coord(x, y-1));       
    // position dessous
    if(y < len-1)
        if(grille[x][y] == grille[x][y+1]) 
            unvisited.add(new Coord(x, y+1));
```

And I can't find the other points ...

I try to take the list unvisited, for each elements I search by line and column, then add to visited, and remove from unvisited, while unvisited is not empty, but I can't have a good result..

Output error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
```

I hope you understand what I want, and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: You have to use an Iterator if you want to remove elements while iterating to stop getting that error.

Comment: maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23222712/algorithm-to-find-same-element-from-a-point-in-a-random-matrix) is what you're looking for

Comment: I edit my code to simplify, I tried something else : only get the right, left, top or bottom point that has the same value :

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a 4-connectivity problem to put a name on it. And you are looking for the biggest region. Here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling you have some algorithms.
NB:  m-connectivity and 8-connectivity are with diagonals, careful here.